# How to declare a vector in header and then allocate it

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, header, declaration

Normally I would define a new array and vector with size n in C++ like this:

```
int* xArray = new int[n];
vector<int> yVector(n);
```

But now I have a class Maze which has a header. The arrays and vectors are supposed to be declared in the header and then allocated in f.ex. the constructor.

The arrays are declared in Maze.h like this:

```
class Maze {
public:
    int* xArray;
}
```

And then allocated in Maze.cpp like this:

```
xArray = new int[n];
```

Now I can use xArray from any function in the class Maze.

But what is the equivalent way to declare and allocate vectors? This is what I tried:

In Maze.h:

```
class Maze {
public:
    vector<int> yVector;
}
```

In Maze.cpp:

```
yVector(n);
```

But when compiling I get:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<int>) (int)’
 yVector(n);
```

So does it think that yVector is a function, and that I am trying to call the function? I tried to specify that this is a class field by writing `this->yVector(n);` instead, but that made no difference.

Next I tried putting `vector<int> yVector(n);` in the constructor. It compiles. But when I later try to use `yVector[0]` in another function I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, so I guess all I did was declare a new, local vector, which is not what I wanted.

So how am I supposed to define class vectors when using a header file?

Comment: Post real code. There is no `yArray` anywhere in sight.

Comment: It seems you have your code in `Maze`'s constructor (you might want to show your actual implementation). If so, have a look at member initializer lists.

Comment: Please post your `Maze` constructor.

Comment: Don't post "real code"; post a valid [MCVE].

Comment: This has nothing to do with headers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you're looking for is [std::vector::reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/).
Note that you still need to `push_back` elements into the vector after doing reserve. It only makes sure that the `capacity` is enough to store requested number of elements.

Or, alternatively you can create a new vector in your constructor and copy it to the member.

```
vector<int> temp_vec(n);
yVector = temp_vec;
```